# Tx Hold’em All-in

Tags: texas-hold-em

No limit Tx Hold’em, 2 players left, pre-flop, cards not dealt yet, BB 1000, player #1 goes all-in for 300: can player#2(BB) call the 300 or must he/she bet the 1000BB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules Clarification Needed Please](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/rules-clarification-needed-please)

Answer (score 0):

The wording you used isn't exactly the clearest. How I interrupted your wording is that **only two players left in the game**, i.e. everyone else is busted or it was a headsup game.

Given there are two players left and player 2 is already the Big Blind, he or she needs to do nothing, they have inherently called already. The BB would naturally be considered a call. Pot would be 600 chips, player 2 would only have to put 300 in and as such would get back 700.

Now as an addition to your point. Let's imagine there are other players in the  game. Let's say we have 3 players. Let's say Player 1 and 2 are unchanged, but we now have a Player 3 in a middle position who limps to 1,000 BB. Action remains unchanged to Player 1 who still goes all in for 300, and now it gets back to Player 2. Yes they will need to put in the 1,000 (already done as you said they are BB) as there is another player in the pot. In this case you will have a side pot that Player 1 can win of 900 chips, and a main pot for Player 2 and 3 of 1,400. Bet can continue as normal between Player's 2 and 3.

Now for your scenario you mentioned no cards have been dealt, and only two players are left, i.e. we're heads-up and a player is all in, which means they're the Small Blind. In this case just put in 300 per player as we're heads-up and Player 1 is all-in automatically. Deal the hand face-up as it's an all-in.

What this sounds to me is a home game, where Player 1 has survived the all-in and thinks they should get to win the 1,000 chip as that is what the BB is, i.e. they should now have 1,300 chips. If this is the case Player 1 is absolutely wrong, regardless of what the blinds are a player is only entitled to win what they have wagered, i.e. as mentioned already 300 is their all-in, as such 300 is what is needed to call, therefore pot of 600 is what Player 1 can win, regardless of what the BB actually is.

Answer (score -2):

Well a player can only get action on the money they can bet. Since player one only has three hundred thepot will then be six hundred meaning player two is getting back anything of his bet over 300. Rules may differ house to house, and are comepletly different for limit games. And often slow floor people and dealers do not know the difference and will rule the same for limit and no limit games. In limit the big bling when all in for less then the required big blind gets action on his blind as though he posted the full amount of the big blind. I guess to keep it simple for everyone. But in no limit it is only action on what the big blind posted like any all in bet.